# Scale image size (Image control on an Access form)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I've done this before, but I'm working in 2010 now and it doesn't seem to be working.

I'm trying to make a thumbnail view of an image control. The pictures I store (text field, just linking to a directory) are large and have their own form to open and view them at resolution, but I want to display a small thumbnail of the picture.

I have an image control with the control source set to the image field of my record source. It changes fine with I navigate records, but it shows a zoomed "window" of the image instead of scaling the image down to a thumbnail like it worked in the past.

I've tried the "size to fit" option, thinking that would do the trick but it doesn't.

Is there a different property that I could use? I don't mind writing a little VBA for this either, but I figured it would have worked by just using the form controls.

Comment: I just tried this using a regular old `Image` control in Access 2010 and it worked fine for me when I changed its dimensions to something "thumbnail sized" (0.5" x 0.5") and set the `Size Mode` property to `Zoom`. Also, I'm curious: I could not seem to find a "size to fit" option - where is that?

Comment: You right click on the control to see the size to fit option - It's not in the form properties. I set it to zoom and it worked though, thanks for the clue. I figured zoom would have done the opposite or something. Weird that "size to fit" doesn't size it to fit though.

Comment: Ah, okay, it doesn't seem to make any difference to my test form. As I said, it works fine for me with two .jpg files of very different dimensions. They both get shrunk down to 0.5" square.

Comment: @GordThompson Yup, the "zoom" property seems to scale it well. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I just tried this using a regular old `Image` control in Access 2010 and it worked fine for me when I changed its dimensions to something "thumbnail sized" (0.5" x 0.5") and set the `Size Mode` property to `Zoom`.